# How to use optimize processors performance in OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, multiprocessing, frame-rate

I'm a beginner in multiprocessing on OpenCV-Python. I'm using Raspberry Pi 2 Model B (Quad-core x 1GHz). And I'm trying to optimize FPS with a very simple example.

This is my code:

webcam.py

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Webcam:
    def __init__(self):
        self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video2')
        self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()[1]
        self.current_frame = cv2.resize(self.current_frame,(1280,720), cv2.INTER_AREA)

def _update_frame(self):
    self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()[1]

def _resize(self):
    self.current_frame = cv2.resize(self.current_frame,(1280,720), cv2.INTER_AREA)

def resizeThread(self):
    p2 = Process(target=self._resize, args=())
    p2.start()

def readThread(self):
    p1 = Process(target=self._update_frame, args=())
    p1.start()

def get_frame(self):
    return self.current_frame
```

main.py

```
from webcam import Webcam
import cv2
import time
webcam = Webcam()
webcam.readThread()
webcam.resizeThread()
while True:
    startF = time.time()
    webcam._update_frame()
    webcam._resize()
    image = webcam.get_frame()
    print  (image.shape)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    endF = time.time()
    print ("FPS: {:.2f}".format(1/(endF-startF)))
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I only got FPS around 10 FPS.

```
FPS: 11.16
(720, 1280, 3)
FPS: 10.91
(720, 1280, 3)
FPS: 10.99
(720, 1280, 3)
FPS: 10.01
(720, 1280, 3)
FPS: 9.98
(720, 1280, 3)
FPS: 9.97
```

So how can I optimize multiprocessing to increase FPS? Did I use multiprocessing correctly?

Thank you so much for helping me,

Toan

Comment: I think there are quite a few issues there. 1) Your indentation in `webcam.py` is wrong. 2) Your processes are called threads which isn't helpful. 3) You are timing a single frame rather than averaging over 100 or more, so you will get big variations. 4) Your *"processes"* read one frame and exit as far as I can see - this is the biggest issue.

Comment: The idea is to use Threading to grab frames in one thread and then show/process the frames in another thread. The FPS performance boost will come from I/O latency reduction. If you're application is bottle necked due to I/O latency those links will help

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, may you edit my code follow your opinions ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @nathancy, thank  you for your great idea. My board has 4 cores and I think using multiprocessing is better than multithread. Do you accept with it ? I hope to see your response. Thank you !

Comment: Well you can't say multiprocessing is better than multithreading or vise versa. They are two different things. Multiprocessing will give you performance increases due to CPU limitations such as in calculations or doing a large number of arithmetic operations. In contrast, multithreading can help when you're not doing something CPU bound such as I/O operations. I think you need to measure your performance and determine where your bottleneck comes from before deciding which one to use

Comment: Hi @nathancy, it's so clearly. Of course, I will compare. Do you think my codes are correctly ? If not, may you help me to fix my codes ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will help with the multiprocessing aspect, but you can optimize your cv2.resize call in two ways:

- Easy: Change the interpolation arg to INTER_LINEAR and do iterative downscaling by a factor of 2 <sup>*</sup>. This will produce about the same quality, but faster.
- Harder: You could do the resizing on the GPU, as it's a very appropriate device for resizing

<sup>*</sup> Of course, the last step in the loop should use a factor that is less than two, to make sure the result has your desired size.

Comment: Hi @Stenfan, I changed INTER_AREA to INTER_LINEAR. And how to resizing on GPU, It's sound strange. May you tell me more info ? Thank you so much !

Comment: About resizing on the GPU: the easiest way is by using OpenGL for GPGPU purposes. Basically: Render a textured quad to an FBO, with texture minification.